# DTO mapper as a service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, service, automapper

I'm working on a project that is using auto mapper as the method of translating domain objects to View models.

It's currently sitting behind an IMapperService. The current implementation of this service forwards calls into auto mapper (the same method signature).

I understand that should a different mapping library be used it'd be easy to swap out.

However I figured the mappings would need to be rewritten along other tweaks to the application.

I think it unlikely that the auto mapper implementation would be swapped half way through a project.

I want to remove the dependency on this service and tightly couple (never thought I'd say that) my controllers to auto mapper since I figured the mapping logic is tied to auto mapper anyway.

Has anyone ever abstracted the auto mapper map calls into a service, if so; did you ever swap the mapper half way through or at the end of the project?

Does abstracting auto mapper calls into a service seem overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the approach that you have mentioned when using AutoMapper, I prefer to program to an interface whenever possible.  The calling code (controller/service) should only care about the 'what' (X is mapped to Y) rather than the 'how' (AutoMapper maps X to Y).

If the chances that you may switch out AutoMapper for something else is low and you don't want to introduce a custom service then you could look at injecting [IMappingEngine](https://github.com/SteveDunn/AutoMapperThreadSafe/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/IMappingEngine.cs).  This saves having calls to the static Mapper.Map function and can be easily mocked for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In our controllers/services the mapping is usually a single call to AutoMapper Map. This would make it simple to change should we want a different mapping engine. The more challenging changes would be to the mappings themselves.

As for overkill; I believe it is. If you anticipate that there is a high probability that the mapping engine will change then abstract the mapping engine. Otherwise don't do it as it's more code to maintain, more things that can go wrong and more code to understand. The acronym YAGNI springs to mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I was thinking. I'm going to leave this question open a bit longer.